# API Gateway - Access-Control-Allow-Origin with Multiple Values

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a Rest API with some configuration for the CORS. I cannot use `*` so I need to specify a list of origins that can access the app. I have a Parameter called `AllowedOrigins` which is `http://localhost:4200,http://somethingelse.com`

```
Resources:
 RestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Cors:
        AllowOrigin: !Sub "'${AllowedOrigins}'"
        AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type'"
        AllowCredentials: true
        MaxAge: "'3600'"
```

The OPTIONS method returns the headers but I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://myApi.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/cars' from
> origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight
> request doesn't pass access control check: The
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
> 'http://localhost:4200,http://somethingelse.com', but only one is
> allowed.

How can I filter the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to only send one value?